# If a not good attribute is selected for decision tree, there is a consistent hypothesis here?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, decision-tree, pattern-recognition

I take a sentence from a note to someone and I am now wondering how this statement can be valid:

> In constructing a decision tree for noise-free data, if a good feature
>   has not been selected for root, we still can create a consistent
>   hypothesis.

It doesn't make sense to me: why can we still create a consistent decision tree in this condition?

Remark: if `f` is the target function, we say hypothesis `h` is consistent if it agrees with `f` on all examples

Comment: Good feature in what terms? Information gain? I think that there may be problems where even selecting a root node that is not the best in terms of maximization of the information gain, a consistent hypothesis can still be created.

Comment: I mean, it depends on how you measure good, and in any case on the data set, what prevents you choosing a "bad enough" feature for the root and the best features for all the children to obtain a consistent hypothesis? Unless I am not missing something here I would say this is highly dependant on the data set (and on your luck then).

Answer (score 0):

Unless I have not misunderstood the question, I would say that statement is true.

It is not the simplest thing to come up with a quick example but here it is (sorry for my poor paint skills).

[image]

In this picture we can see how choosing as root the feature `x2` returns the max information gain and allows us to find a consistent hypothesis with a minimal decision tree.
In fact `h(x) = "cross"` if `x2 > 1`.

This does not prevent us to find a consistent hypothesis choosing the worst feature, `x1`, as root.
Going this way we would have an initial branching over `x1`:

`x1 < 1` from here we would then perform a successive branching over `x2`

`x1 > 1` and from here the same.

This way we would obtain `h(x) = "cross"` if `x1 < 1 && x2 > 1`. `h(x) = "circle"` otherwise. Thus a consistent hypothesis again.